# Quadrilateral inequality

Tags: geometry

If the sides ab,bc,cd,da of a quadrilateral abcd are in descending order of magnitude show that angle cda > angle cba

Please help me with question 15. I have applied triangle inequality to every side possible but can't get a good equation.

Answer (score 2):

This image seems to present a counterexample...

[image]